# Why does the (relativistic) mass of an object increase when its speed approaches that of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, mass, velocity

I'm reading *Nano: The Essentials* by T. Pradeep and I came upon this statement in the section explaining the basics of scanning electron microscopy.

> *However, the equation breaks down when the electron velocity approaches the speed of light as mass increases. At such velocities, one needs to do relativistic correction to the mass so that it becomes[...]*

We all know about the famous theory of relativity, but I couldn't quite grasp the "why" of its concepts yet. This might shed new light on what I already know about time slowing down for me if I move faster.

Why does the (relativistic) mass of an object increase when its speed approaches that of light?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The complete relevant text in [the book](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=gPRPYyfZJvkC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=%22However,+the+equation+breaks+down+when+the+electron+velocity+approaches+the+speed+of+light+as+mass+increases.%22&source=bl&ots=Kq_ZtVxXBw&sig=q5zcvkELqDY0XoK74OtDU-Syiq4&hl=zh-TW&ei=uA_9TKfmM4WycLimrfQO&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22However%2C%20the%20equation%20breaks%20down%20when%20the%20electron%20velocity%20approaches%20the%20speed%20of%20light%20as%20mass%20increases.%22&f=false) is

> The de Broglie wave equation relates the velocity of the electron with its wavelength, $\lambda = h/mv$ ... However, the equation breaks down when the electron velocity approaches the speed of light as mass increases. ...

Actually, the [de Broglie wavelength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie_wavelength#The_de_Broglie_relations) should be
$$ \lambda = \frac hp, $$
where $p$ is the momentum. While $p = mv$ in classical mechanics, in special relativity the actual relation is
$$ \mathbf p = \gamma m \mathbf v = \frac{m\mathbf v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $$
where $m$ is the rest mass. If we still need to make the equation $p = mv$ correct, we introduce the concept of "[relativistic mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_mass#The_relativistic_mass_concept)" $M = \gamma m$ which increases with $v$.

Comment: Looking at the formula it is not valid for rest mass zero (photon), correct? Beginner's question: this goes without saying? So the Newtonian force-impulse formula is valid only for non-relativistic velocities i.e. in daily life which is slow?

Answer (score 88):

The mass (the **true mass** which physicists actually deal with when they calculate something concerning relativistic particles) **does not change with velocity**. The mass (the true mass!) is an intrinsic property of a body, and it does not depends on the observer's frame of reference. I strongly suggest to read [this popular article](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0602037) by Lev Okun, where he calls the concept of relativistic mass a "pedagogical virus".

What actually changes at relativistic speeds is the **dynamical law** that relates momentum and energy depend with the velocity (which was already written). Let me put it this way: trying to ascribe the modification of the dynamical law to a changing mass is the same as trying to explain non-Euclidean geometry by redefining $\pi$!

Why this law changes is the correct question, and it is discussed in the answers here.

Comment: This is _the_ correct answer.

Comment: @Killercam, yep. +1 for Okun

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It just advises the OP to ask the question in different language.

Comment: @Ben It's not an issue of asking the same question in different language. Suppose I ask 'why is the moon made of blue cheese'. The question as stated makes no physical sense. If you change the language so that it makes sense, it becomes a different question.

Comment: Yeah, it would be foolish to try explaining non-Euclidean geometry by redefining pi factorial.

Comment: @kingfrito_5005 $\pi ! \approx$ 7.188082728976032702082194345124758718559301763968437162... :)

Comment: Indeed. To add a historical note, terminology has changed over time. "Mass" used to mean $\gamma m$, now it means $m$. This is a change of convention, not of physics.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say "rest mass" and "relativistic mass", and avoid unadorned "mass" in relativity on the ground that it is ambiguous? Those that disapprove of the concept of relativistic mass could discourage its use. If and when rest mass becomes the only type of mass anyone ever talks about, *then* one could reasonably propose shortening it to just "mass". To have most relativists  using "mass" to mean "rest mass" while most physicists use it to mean "relativistic mass", and nearly all nonphysicists likewise, is causing a lot of confusion and causing a lot of time to be wasted.

Comment: Likewise, unadorned "energy" is at present ambiguous, and what is currently called "energy" by most relativists should perhaps instead be called "total energy" (because it includes the energy equivalent of the rest mass), distinguished from the other energies such as "rest energy", "kinetic energy", "potential energy" and so on. The fact that both "mass" and "energy" each have at least two meanings, and that they tend to be defined in terms of each other, at least to some extent, aggravates the problem greatly by a sort of synergy, so to speak. At least, when speaking to nonrelativists?

Comment: Arguably, it would have been a good thing had relativistic mass never been publicized, but the idea that mass means relativistic mass has taken root now, and I don't think saying (like Lewis Epstein) that "there is only one kind of mass" helps. The majority take that to mean that there is only relativistic mass. Teaching that "mass" means "invariant mass" (i.e. rest mass) and avoiding all mention of relativistic mass has not been effective in discouraging the use of the concept of relativistic mass, and has allowed the confusion to persist. You can't enforce a meaning change here, it seems.

Comment: @MoonKnight care to explain why it does ? (not being annoying here; I am really just wanting to know) saying "this is correct" isn't very explanatory :)

Comment: I think the answer explains the difference between rest mass and inertial mass very well. Are you asking me to rewrite this answer using different wording? What don't you understand about the above and I will see if I can assist?

Answer (score 15):

There is a point of view, that under the term "the mass" one must mean "the **rest** mass".

From that point of view there is obviously no dependence of the (rest) mass on the speed of an object. And, therefore, the mass of an object does not increase when its speed increases.

The correct (from that point of view) way to talk about the phenomenon is to say that *with increase of the speed of an object you need more and more energy in order to make it move faster*.

Of course there is no fundamental controversy between this point of view and that of many books and articles. But the usage of the concept of "relativistic mass" makes things much more complicated, even if it was introduced in pursuit of simplicity.

Comment: The phenomenon you are talking about (one in the italics) is actually quite similar to definition of inertial mass. Inertial mass measures how *hard* it is to move an object. And this is why the concept of relativistic mass is useful. It is similar to inertial mass. On the other hand, invariant mass is just a number that characterizes the particle but has nothing to do with dynamics. I think properly distinguishing between various concepts of masses takes some time and thinking (and there is also gravitational mass and related equivalence principle but let's leave that for another time).

Comment: Inertial mass measures how hard it is to move an object. Yes. But note that you can change the speed of an object in different directions. Do deal with that you will need to introduce "logitudinal" and "transverse inertial masses". I support people, saying that talking about "inertial mass" is an overcomplication leading to mistakes and "terminological swamp".

Comment: Point taken Kostya. These past few days I've been shown quite a huge heap of evidence that any concept of mass different from invariant mass is really too messy to be worth even talking about :-) And I really have to wonder why I was introduced to all these things when I was learning SR myself (from books and also at our uni SR course). They seem just an unnecessary baggage now. But perhaps it is still useful to know these concepts exist? I am not sure.

Comment: I had the same confusion about this unecessary baggage after I dscovered all this mess.  The person, who promotes the "only rest mass" point of view is Lev Okun. The great, very basic and free book on that topic: "ENERGY AND MASS IN RELATIVITY THEORY" by Lev B Okun

Comment: "... you need more and more energy in order to make it move faster. ..." - which is not the case with photons as they already are on c speed. As it occurs to me having read: emitting a photon does not "need" energy at all, the energy the photon needs makes up the photon per se.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes the same word "mass" is used with different meanings. There are two different quantities associated with the word "mass":

- A quantity that physicists *usually* call "mass", which is an intrinsic property of the object and does *not* depend on how fast it is moving. I'll use the symbol $m$ for this quantity.
- A synonym for the object's energy $E$, but expressed in mass-like units as $E/c^2$. This is sometimes called the object's "relativistic mass" and it *does* depend on how fast the object is moving (because the object's energy does).   I'll use the symbol $m_R$ for this quantity.

We are already familiar with the fact that the kinetic energy of an object is higher when the object is moving faster. "Relativistic mass" is just a synonym for the object's total energy, expressed in mass-like units. From this perspective, consider the question again:

> Why does the (relativistic) mass of an object increase when its speed approaches that of light?

Answer: Because the object's energy increases. "Relativistic mass" is just a synonym for the object's energy, expressed in mass-like units. Why did people ever start using the name "relativistic mass" for the object's energy?  I don't know. In my experience, most physicists just call it energy.

Here are some equations to help clarify things:

The energy $E$, momentum $p$, speed $v$, and mass $m$ of an object are related to each other according to these equations:
$$
   E^2 - (pc)^2 = (mc^2)^2
\hskip2cm
  v = \frac{pc^2}{E}
$$
where $c$ is the speed of light. The $m$ in the first equation is what physicists usually mean when they use the word "mass". It is an intrinsic property of the object and does *not* depend on the object's speed.  The object's energy $E$ and momentum $p$ do depend on the speed, and they do so in such a way that the combination $E^2-(pc)^2$ does *not* depend on the speed. That's why this particular combination is interesting, and that's why the $m$ on the right-hand side of the equation deserves a special name: mass.

To relate this to the "relativistic mass" $m_R$ (which, again, is *not* used by the majority of physicists in my experience), re-arrange the second equation shown above to get
$$
   p = \frac{E}{c^2}v.
$$
If we  use $m_R$ as an abbreviation for $E/c^2$, then this becomes
$$
   p = m_R v,
$$
which looks *superficially* like the more familiar low-speed approximation $p=mv$. This resemblance is also misleading, though, because the energy $E$ (and therefore $m_R$) is a function of $v$. The momentum $p$ is *not* really proportional to the velocity $v$, except approximately when $v\ll c$.

Comment: I'm afraid we have to blame Einstein for relativistic mass. Before Einstein, people noticed that something funny happens with the momentum & kinetic energy of high speed electrons. Special relativity solved the mystery via relativistic mass; it took a few decades for people to realise that it's better to work with invariant mass and that relativistic mass is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Considering your final sentence, is the following understanding a possible one: The closer to c you are the less you need acceleration to have "energy"? (Thus, emission of a particle should not be considered acceleration.)

Comment: @PeterBernhard To have energy, acceleration isn't needed. That's already true in the nonrelativistic approximation, where the kinetic energy of a particle is $E=mv^2/2$. Is your question about how much acceleration is needed to change the energy by a given amount?

Comment: Very helpful to call up E=mv2/2.  As there is no "halfing" in E=mc2  my understanding is being confirmed that emission of a photon does, in your words above,  "not need acceleration" (emissiion is not accelaration, rest mass is zero). As it occurs: what is the energy of a photon the mass of which is zero, using  E=mc2  (or even) E=mv2/2. - yes, my question is about assuming that the closer to c a particle is the less energy you need to put in to get NonKinetic energy. "Feel free" to elaborate in your answer about momentum, weight, being defined using "slow" velocities, as you say in final.

Answer (score 2):

In special relativity the actual invariant is the magnitude of the covariant [energy momentum 4-vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum) $(E_0/c_0, p_x,p_y,p_z)$, not the apparent mass itself.  See also the section on "momentum in 4 Dimensions", [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity#Momentum_in_4D).  The apparent mass in a moving frame is just a projection.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it simple (with a link):

Special Relativity

"The relativistic increase of mass happens in a way that makes it impossible to accelerate an object to light speed: The faster the object already is, the more difficult any further acceleration becomes. The closer the object's speed is to light speed, the greater the increase in inertial mass; to reach light speed exactly would require an infinitely strong force acting on the body. This enforces special relativity's speed limit: No material object can be accelerated to light speed.

The increase in inertial mass is part of a more general phenomenon, the relativistic equivalence of mass and energy: If one adds energy to a body, one automatically increases its mass; if one takes energy away from it, one decreases its mass. In the case of acceleration, the object in question gains kinetic energy ("movement energy"), and this increase in energy automatically means an increase in mass."

See http://www.einstein-online.info/elementary/specialRT/emc

This, to most, helps clear things up without adding complexity. You are, of course, welcome to delve deeper.

Comment: As many comments & answers on this page mention, relativistic mass is not used in modern treatments of special relativity because it's often awkward to work with, confusing, and potentially misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Relativistic mass, *by definition*, is the quantity $m_\mathrm{rel}(v) := \gamma(v)\ m$, where $m$ is the intrinsic, or "rest", mass. Mathematically, it increases because the Lorentz factor $\gamma(v)$ increases with increasing speed $v$.

However, a more physical reason is that this "relativistic mass" is really just the *total energy* $E_\mathrm{tot}$, consisting of the combination of the rest energy and kinetic energy of a material body, interpreted in units of mass, by the mass-energy equivalence relation $E = mc^2$: $m_\mathrm{rel}(v) = \frac{E_\mathrm{tot}(v)}{c^2}$. It is thus seen to increase because objects moving at higher speeds have more kinetic energy, and thus also, total energy.

Comment: Ref. to "... at higher speeds have more kinetic energy, and thus also, total energy..." 
Do objects close to c in fact have "more kinetic" energy? What is kinetic energy? It is mass and velocity. By definition you might say, to the contrary: the more objects are accelerated the lesser their kinetic energy because the lesser the extent of conversion of impulse to "kinetic energy". Just a thought! Their "total" energy" seems to increase, not their kinetic speed.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, mass and energy are the same thing. They are two "points of view" of the same reality.

From the "point of view" (inertial frame) of an electron, its mass does not increase, its speed is always zero.

From the "point of view" (inertial frame) of a stationary observer, the electron has a very high kinetic energy (some in the mass term and some in the speed term)

From the "point of view" (inertial frame) of a moving observer, the electron has a different kinetic energy (some in the mass term and some in the speed term)

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to intuitively see why the mass increases, consider the following.

- Firstly, nothing can travel faster than the speed of light (this is the premise on which Special Relativity is based)
- Secondly, applying a force to an object will increase its kinetic energy (assuming the force acts in the same direction as the object's motion)

Since kinetic energy $K.E.$ = $m v^2/2$, if $v$ is limited to $c$, then as $v$ approaches $c$ the only way for $K.E.$ to increase is for $m$ to increase.

This isn't a fully mathematical answer, but may help you to intuit why the mass increases.

Comment: I have never before heard that special relativity is based on the premise that nothing can move faster than light.  Elementary SR usually says 1) The speed of light is constant in all frames.  2) All physical laws are the same in inertial frames.

Comment: @Mark: correct. SR says no such thing and actually admits existence of tachyons. The sectors "faster than light" and "slower than light" are obviously dual to each other and SR doesn't distinguish between them at all. The reason why we don't want tachyons is an additionally assumption of causality.

Comment: +1 @Sam, I was also thinking along the same line you did, relating mass to speed and energy.

Comment: This argument is wrong. Relativistic kinetic energy doesn't equal $(1/2)mv^2$, and doesn't approach a limit as $v$ approaches $c$.

Comment: This is simply wrong.  Basically beeing limited to c does not mean that you have to push on a equation that contain c. Just go to c and stop. Second , c emerged as a limit , It is not taken as a postulate.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are having this confusion is because you think that mass should not change. As many have said above, and I would reiterate, REST MASS is the property that does not change for any particle, ever. For eg, the rest mass of a photon is zero. So, basically, when einstein put forward the very famous equation, $E = M.C^2$, he meant very clearly that mass IS energy, and energy IS mass. They are just one and the same thing!.

Now, tell me, if energy increases, would the mass not increase? And why not in daily life, the answer is because $ \delta M =  \frac{\delta E}{c^2}$...and so, if your energy changes by an amount comparable to $c^2$, only then would you be able to observe a change in mass.

Hope it helps...if any more doubts arise, please comment!

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following helps, too:

For the "why" think about Einstein's photon from the sun being deviated by gravitation of the moon during some eclipse of the 20th century. The photon's direction was deviated by gravitational force. What about its velocity? Had it been accelerated by gravitational mass?
The answer is "of course not" - by definition there is no speed exceeding speed of light the photon brought along from the sun.

Thus, it comes to no surprise that the following is prone to be considered falsely claimed: If a photon is accelerated (by a gravitational field) a   shift of frequency occurs. There does exist red shift and - even -  violet shift of frequency, thus there does exist loss and gain of energy, shown by change of frequency, not velocity of the particle. This gain of energy (the cause  is acceleration, the consequence is energy)  may be named gain of mass as the change of energy the particle bears will  translate into Newtonian  momentum should the particle "hit any floor" (sun sail).

Velocity, in fact, is what the question is about. Why does it take that much to "accelerate" to speed of light. The question does not ask: Why is it so difficult to pump up the energy of a particle moving closer to c. The Why is about the speed, velocity. The name is "mass" because particles moving close to c will impart regular impulse, thus regular acceleration, velocity, when they interact with masses (hitting any floor).

Assuming that any particle close to c has the zero rest mass property of the photon, I think one way to answer about the "Why" is:

The closer an object moves at speed of light the more that particle is able to transform  any input of kinetic energy into non-kinetic energy ("frequency", "wave function"). This energy   may be called mass as that non-accelerated particle or object is able  to transform this non-kinetic energy into kinetic impulse (only "rest" mass of photons is zero) when "hitting".

The question "Why" thus asks about a mechanism that transforms kinetic impulse into energy (named mass) and energy to kinetic impulse which in my opinion is not known.

Answer (score -1):

The mass of object changes when its speed approaches zero because according to Einstein postulates of theory of relativity all the laws are same in all inertial frames and speed of light remains constant in inertial frame in vacuum. All the concepts of relativity are based on these two postulates. As one can not add any speed in speed of light, the Lorentz transformation equations are derived and using these variation of mass with velocity relation. Almost every concept of Physics changes at a speed comparative to speed of light.

[One can see the derivation here](http://www.winnerscience.com/relativity/variation-of-mass-with-velocity-and-its-derivation/)

Comment: "when its speed approaches zero" - is rarely heard. What is speed zero? you need some relativistic origo point of view that is not moved either, and this means has the same "velocity". That said - it occurs, suddenly, that inert mass of impuls does seem to differ from gravitational mass, as two object that have "speed zero" to each other would not be able to accelerate each other by "hitting", i.e. Newtonian impulse, hoever, both having "speed zero" they would still be able to exert gravity on each other.  Interesting point! Again, velocity is a necessity for acceleration...(?)

Answer (score -3):

There are plenty of misinformation here.

> "The mass of a body is not constant; it varies with changes in its energy."
>
> **[Einstein, A. The Meaning of Relativity, Princeton University Press, 1988]**

See also Section 10, Dynamics of the Slowly Accelerated Electron, of the paper 'On the Electrodynamics of moving Bodies' [Einstein, A. Annalen der Physik, 17, 1905]. Also see Section 29, Ponderomotive forces. Dynamics of the electron, in the book 'Theory of Relativity' [Pauli, W. Dover Publications Inc., 1981, (first published in 1921 in German, first published in English in 1958)]

Comment: You should probably be aware that the modern take on relativity does *not* group $\gamma$ with $m$ and call $\gamma m$ "the relativistic mass", but rather takes the invariant square of the energy-momentum four-vector (what in the old language would have been called the "rest mass") to be the definition of the (only!) mass of the object. The math is the same, but (1) it engenders less confusion and (2) the emphasis on invariants help to make problems easier.

Comment: @dmckee I personally feel that relativistic mass confused and brake my understanding along years.  I am a chemist and  always felt that, besides observables, mass should intimately reletad to the baryonic constitution of a body.  However, or exactly for that, I still have trouble on seeing why m does increase with T. Perhaps the concept of relativistic mass is useful for that (in a microscopic view)....

Comment: @dmckee ..... not sure that I cleary convey what my concern is.  Not very easy to formulate. ..  I tried to follow debates on mass energy and found EVEN three four schools of thinking! Convertible but not the same / the same / not the same and not convertibles / .... I got lost as I found myself fine with multiple but different leading logics. Can you point me to something on this?

Answer (score -3):

If I accept true mass as being constant then defining increases to such a given mass is impossible (see Newton) because I can sit and watch it forever at rest or in motion: a given mass is a given mass, and a given quantity does not change, regardless of speed or energy applied. The effect(s) then, either perception or theoretical, that creates the illusion that mass changes, is better described by a more accurate theory than Einstein put forth or modifying Einstein to a more accurate level.

On another note, the arbitrary  Einsteinian speed of light limit for velocity is similar to the ceiling of the 4 minute mile. There is no proof that such a limit exists. Until we get past this arbitrary barrier and explain these phenomena in a more useful way we will never achieve deep space travel.

To make such travel possible we must get beyond mass particles into non-mass particles that pass easily through the light barrier. They might or might not exist at this point. In the future these particles will be the building blocks and the carriers of information necessary to transfer life to habitable planets throughout the universe. Granted, your body will not beam up but your current conscionsness and DNA sequence might: A quick resurrection and **you are you** three galaxies away.

Granted that I am not a physicist and I am an iconoclast when it comes to accepting dogma. To me, devolving honest perception into theoretical soup does not make you any more informed on the true nature of mass vis a vis energy and velocity. You simply have learned what someone else learned and thought it to be true, i.e. the appeal to authority that Einstein believed and said it therefore it is true.

Comment: "There is no proof that such a limit exists." There's tons of proof. [Particle accelerators](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_accelerator)  routinely accelerate particles to speeds higher than 0.99c, but they've never managed to break the lightspeed barrier.