# Is there a unit system, where all physical laws looks nice?

Tags: units, physical-constants, absolute-units

And by nice looking law I mean with no constants. I mean, what would we need to set, so all laws would without those nasty constants in front of them? (I mean all of them, also $\pi$!)
What would it mean?.

What I am trying to say with this question is: Is there a universal language, do particles and gravity live in the same space? If gravity and quantum world should go together, there should be one basis, where you don't need to use any constants.

Comment: You can find out yourself: Set all constants to $1$ (except $\pi$ of course!) and see what happens. The laws are fixed, setting the constants just changes our choice of units. [Spoiler: You don't get rid of $\pi$.]

Comment: @ACuriousMind Wouldn't you be able to absorb $pi$ into some constant.

Comment: @jinawee: I would be very impressed if you could do so in a way that makes the $\pi$ in the area or circumference formulae $A = \pi r^2$ or $C = 2\pi r $ disappear (and these are often the underlying reason $\pi$ shows up in physical laws).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Prove it! You don't seem to understand my question - my question is directly aiming to prove that assumptions of all constants equaling one is contradictory to $\pi=1$!

Comment: $\pi$ is what it is, it's a number (properly defined for example as double the first positive zero of the cosine). $\pi = 1$ is simply false. The value of $\pi$ is *not* tunable.

Comment: @ACuriousMind why wouldn't be? $\pi$ is a number, but what stops you from defining vector space as $X$ with isomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to X, \phi: x'=\pi^{-1} x$?

Comment: There is no such universal "units language" as each branch of physics has a set of convenient units (Gaussian for astronomers, natural units for HEP, geometric units for geometric physics, etc) that are useful in their subfield. However, you can always use $\sim$ to ignore constants, e.g. $\mathbf F\sim q^2/r^2\hat{\mathbf r}$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Well, I was thinking of Einstein's equations. Something more "physical".

Comment: @jinawee: Sneaky ninja editor, you!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here's why rescaling units won't get rid of $\pi$:

The circumference of a circle is $C = 2\pi r$. *Note that $C$ and $r$ are measured in the same unit, both are units of length.* Now rescale lengths as $l' = c l$ with an arbitrary constant $c$ (might be $\pi$, but doesn't matter). Plugging in yields

$$C' = cC = c 2 \pi r = 2 \pi c r = 2 \pi r'$$

So you haven't changed the circumference law at all. Thus, you don't get rid of $\pi$.

Comment: No, you have $C = r'$, which amounts to saying that your new unit of length is the length of the radius of a circle with circumference 1, but if you express the circumference also in your new unit of length, you have $C' = \frac{C}{2\pi} = \frac{2\pi r}{2\pi} = r = 2\pi r'$. *If you rescale, you have to rescale **all** lengths*, else you measure circumference and radius in two different units, which is patently absurd.

Comment: Right, that should be $r$ not $r'$. Then it holds. However, that does not prove that by rescaling you won't have for example Einstein's equations without $\pi$. And something else with $\pi$(some other law I mean).

Comment: Please, understand, I am aiming at Physics laws, not mathematical formulae. $C=2\pi r$ is not a physics law. It exists independently from physics.

Comment: The factors of $\pi$ in physics arise mainly out of (solid) angle integrals (which are, in turn, essentially there because we intergrate along the circumference of a circle or the area of a sphere). Their value is also independent of rescalings, by the same argument I illustrated above. The part about gravity and quantum theories you just edited into your question is totally incomprehensible to me, and suggests there is some more fundamental confusion as to what units are going on.

Answer (score 1):

[Planck units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units) is almost (except coefficients like $\pi$) exactly the unit system you want, and it is frequently used in quantum field theory.

According to its definition:

$c =  G =  \hbar = k_\text{B} = 1 \ $

Comment: Yeah, I know about the Planck's system and geometrized units and Gauss unit system, my question is directly aiming to prove that assumptions of all constants equaling one is contradictory to $\pi=1$!

Comment: Hint: you contradict yourself if you define $c=1$ and $1/4\pi\varepsilon$=1

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing [Fermi estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem), it's convenient to use a "system of units" where
$$
\sqrt{10} = \pi = 3 = 1 = -1 = c
$$
though this is probably more tongue-in-cheek than you were hoping for. For some reason I think of these as "pauper's units," though I'm not sure whether that phrase is my own invention or not.

You might be interested in [this other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112959/44126).