# Why does natural units technique only works in equations in Physics?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, absolute-units

Example where it will not work is $(\frac{A}{B})^m = n$. Set $A=B=1$ and then solve for $m$. 
And example where it will work is:

$(E/c)^2 = p^2+ (mc)^2$.
You can drop $c$ and put it back later by dimensional analysis. What is so special with equations in Physics why it always work?

Comment: What do you mean by "natural units technique"? Is your example meant to be an example of the natural units technique, or of something else? Where are the units involved?

Comment: Hello @ThePhoton. I put an edit.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/113005/44126).

Comment: Can you give an example of what kinds of things A and B are supposed to be? If that is just a math equation clearly the method doesn't work, just as one cannot it to "solve" A+B=4 by setting both to 1. The thing in physics is that parameters have units and scales of measurement, and *these* things make the method work.

Answer (score 0):

It works not only for natural units, for all the sciences if you reconvert the magnitude to his original units, multiplying for the units in the original system that you did 1, using every unit converted to 1 to get the correct dimensions. There is only a way to do it