# Where does Coulomb's constant, $k_e$, come from?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, dimensional-analysis, coulombs-law, physical-constants

I'm familiar with Coulomb's law, $\vec{F} = k_e\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$, and know how to apply it (having used it extensively in practice, on exams, etc). I find that the $\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$ "part" of Coulomb's law is at least somewhat intuitive, however I've never quite understood precisely where Coulomb's constant, $k_e$, comes from.

I know that it can be measured *experimentally*, of course, but where do we get that $k_e = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}$ and, further, how to we get $\epsilon_0 = \frac{1}{\mu_oc^2}$?

I'm looking for both a "rigorous" derivation, and intuition (where possible).

Comment: [Closely related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/113005/44126).

Comment: The very short answer is that $k_e$ (or $\epsilon_0$) is assumed to be a fundamental constant of nature.  It cannot be derived and must be found experimentally.  (This is true even at the level of quantum field theory.  There is a coefficient in the quantum electrodynamics Lagrangian, when not expressed in natural units, that has to be determined experimentally.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that Coulomb’s Law is experimentally determined, though because Maxwell’s equations describe all electromagnetic phenomena you can consider doing it this way (so you can see how the constant $k$ comes about):

Consider this equation which is one of [Maxwell’s equations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations),

$$\oint_S \vec E \cdot \vec{dS} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$$

where this surface integral $S$ is taken over a closed sphere surrounding the charge $Q$ then

$$E (4\pi r^2) = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$$

and given that the electric field $E$ is defined as the force per unit charge ie.,

$$E = \frac{F}{q}$$

then we can write

$$F = \frac{Qq}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}$$

which is [Coulomb’s Law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law).

The [vacuum permitivity constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity) is a measure of how much a vacuum permits an electric field. Most problems we assume that there is nothing else in the space between the charges we are studying, which is why we use $\epsilon_0$. In cases where we do, we use the dielectric constant $\epsilon$ which is a measure of how much the medium permits an electric field.

When we manipulate Maxwell’s equations, we end up with the [electromagnetic wave equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation) and as you can see in the link

$$v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu \epsilon }}$$

where $v$ is the speed of an electromagnetic wave in a region with permeability $\mu$ and permitivity $\epsilon$. Of course if we are in a vacuum this becomes

$$c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}}$$

where $c$ is the speed of light in a vacuum.