# Intuitive question about torque formula

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, statics, intuition

Consider two objects as shown:

[image]

On one side a box with mass 1 kg, 2 m apart from pivot and on the other side two boxes of mass (1 kg each), 1 m apart from pivot, balance a seesaw.
This is the question:
Why, **intuitively**, the two squares (on the right hand side) must be exactly **one** meter apart from pivot and not for example 1.03 m in order to balance the seesaw?
In other words why, intuitively, torque is equal to force times distance; (and the relation is linear); I mean it's
$$T=mgd$$
And not for example:
$$T=m^{1.006}gd^{1.07}$$

Comment: Consider that decimal exponents make no sense for quantities with units. You can argue that rational numbers for exponents are ok, but irrational numbers are definitely non-sensical.

Comment: The preference for small integer powers arising from algebraic manipulation is discussed in [this other answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/113005/44126).

Comment: @rob - I see a discussion about general unitless coefficients, but I missed the part talking about irrational powers.

Answer (score 2):

That is a deep question actually.

The **tldr** answer is that the center of gravity of all the boxes must be over the pivot for balance. And you calculate center of gravity with the weighted sum of the individual weights.

$$ \text{(center)} = \frac{ \sum_{\rm all} \text{(position)*(weight)} }{ \sum_{\rm all} \text{(weight)} } \tag{1}$$

<sub>The term *weighted* sum in mathematics comes exactly from this operation in physics. The weight describes how important each position is.</sub>

But the above is kind of a circular argument, as here in the numerator we have $\text{(position)*(weight)}$ which is exactly what you are asking about. Why the multiplication.

The mathematical answer is that the above equals to the sum of each fractional contribution of position. Each fraction being the individual weight to the total weight (and thus the term *weighted average*).

$$ \text{(center)} = \sum_{\rm all}  \text{(position)} \left( \frac{\text{(weight)}}{\text{(total weight)}} \right) \tag{2}$$

---

The long answer is that each force acts along a line, and when two or more forces add up together there are some rules of geometry that dictate where the resultant force acts though. You learn in high school how to add vectors by placing them on the same origin, which yields the correct magnitude and direction, but this is not sufficient to find out *where* the resultant acts.

So for two **non-parallel** forces acting through separate points, **A** and **B** as seen below the process involves 4 steps.

[image: fig1]

1. Slide each force along their line of action until the forces meet at a point **C**.
2. Combine the forces vectorially (component by component) on the common point.
3. Describe the new line of action of the combined force as parallel to the combined force and through the point **C**.
4. (optional) Slide the combined force along its line of action, back to wherever makes more sense for the problem at hand. For example on the line connecting the two original forces to new point **D**.

<sub>Note with force vectors you are free to slide them along their line of action without changing the problem at hand.</sub>

So what happens when the two forces are **parallel**? Well follow the same process as above, but the point where they meet is at infinity (on the horizon) and when you do the final step #4 the point **D** ends up being mathematically at the weighted sum of the two original forces.

The same argument as above can be done algebraically instead of geometrical by considering the torque about the pivot. Torque is the numerator of expression (1) and the geometry of the problem introduces the concept of a *moment arm* of a force. This means that only the perpendicular distance counts.

$$ \text{(torque)} = \text{(distance)} * \text{(force)} \tag{3a} $$

or in vector form

$$ \vec{\tau} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F} \tag{3b} $$

Balance happens when the sum of all the torques are zero, which has the geometric interpretation that the combined force line of action goes through the pivot.

Answer (score 1):

You may not find conservation of energy any more intuitive than torque, but if you're willing to grant that perpetual motion machines are impossible, there is no way the ratio of distances for balance could be anything other than the inverse of the ratio of weights.  For any other ratio, you'd be able combine multiple seesaws, and the ability to move boxes horizontally from one seesaw to another, to lift boxes vertically "for free".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an intuitive explanation, because if we could measure with a great precision we would see that $m_1d_1 \neq m_2d_2$ indeed.

The expression above is valid in the approximation that the earth radius is so big compared to the distances of the scale that the force of gravity can be considered parallel.

But in reality, that forces have the direction of the center of the earth, and are smaller for bigger distances, considering a straight arm. The force acting at the end of it is smaller than that acting closer to the pivot point.

So you are right about the slight difference from the standard expression.

Comment: For a seesaw of reasonable length, this effect is quite negligible - the end of a 5m-long seesaw is less than 1nm higher than the fulcrum, meaning the force of gravity varies by less than a trillionth of a percent. Unless you're positioning the masses with sub-nanometer accuracy, it doesn't matter. Regardless, you can just do the experiment in an a spaceship undergoing constant linear acceleration and you won't have to worry about non-uniform gravitational fields (to whatever precision you choose). Practical limitations shouldn't preclude intuitive understanding - just idealize the scenario.

Comment: I just want to see it theoretically!   otherwise you have so many variable parameters,for example you can never remove effect of air molecules (movement) on seesaw!

Comment: I think I am in agreement with the assertion that there is no more intuitive explanation to this than to do the math and check that it works (because, after all, Newton's laws are not intuitive at all). But I think this particular argument is not good because the relation is actually accurate/exact if you just consider forces rather than masses (i.e., $F_1r_1 = F_2r_2$ as a condition for rotational equilibrium is exact even if $m_1r_1 = m_2r_2$ is not).

Comment: My point is that the balance of torques is intuitive because we are used to see that it works. A lever is one of the oldest tools.  People of a dense and small asteroid would probably note that the relation was only a very good aproximation.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider this from an energy balance perspective. A circle of twice the radius has twice the circumference, so if the seesaw moves, an object that's 2m from the fulcrum moves twice as far as an object that's 1m from the fulcrum (vertically, horizontally, or along the arc). An object's change in potential energy is proportional to its mass and vertical displacement, so a object that moves some distance vertically has the same change in energy as an object that weighs half as much but moves twice the distance, or an object that weighs twice as much but moves half the distance.

From this, you can see that when you have an 1 kg object at 2m and a 2kg object at 1m, moving the seesaw results in a perfect energy balance. Systems tend to spontaneously move into states with lower energy, like how an imbalanced see-saw will tilt until the higher-torque end is sitting on the ground. In the case of a balanced see-saw, moving the see-saw results in no overall change in potential energy at all, so there is no preference for the see-saw to move in one direction or the other, meaning there is no impetus for it to move at all. If you have two weights of fixed mass and fix the position of one of them, there is exactly *one* place you can put the other weight in order to achieve balance. If you put it anywhere else, the seesaw will seek to lower its potential energy by tilting.

This perhaps moves the goalposts from "why is torque linear" to why is "why is potential energy linear", but that might be a little more intuitive. It comes down to the fact that in a uniform gravitational field, altitude doesn't affect the amount of work you need to do to climb higher - moving from 0m to 1m takes exactly the same amount of work as moving from 1000m to 1001m. This should be intuitive from the fact that the zero point is entirely arbitrary - there's no reason you couldn't define the 0m to 1m change as actually being a 1000m to 1001m change, and the 1000m to 1001m change as a 2000m to 2001m change. If this relationship wasn't linear, the work required to climb higher would depend on your altitude, which you could redefine simply by changing your reference frame. But clearly, choosing a different reference frame cannot change the amount of work required to do something.

Comment: Your argument is consistent with my preferred definition of torque:  Torque is the work per unit angle (as in Joules/radian) that can be done by a force which is acting in a manner that tends to cause a rotation. (This reminds you that there is a distance involved and that you need to be concerned with the direction of the force.) (In rotation: work = torque times angle.)