# Is Relative Permeability $\mu_0$ still $4\pi \times 10^{-7} $H/m?

Tags: physical-constants, si-units

According to [this 2018 article in *Physics Today*](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/do/10.1063/PT.6.2.20181116a/full/), after May 2019 the new SI system fixes, or defines, these seven quantities:

[image]

If the dimensionless fine structure constant  $\frac{e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 hc}$ has a definite value, then $\epsilon_0$ has a fixed value.

But since $$c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}}$$ doesn't this also fix $\mu_0$?

So is $\mu_0$ no longer defined to be exactly $4\pi \times 10^{-7}$ H/m?

Comment: I shd probably see this, but since I do not see epsilon_0 in that list: how do these 7 quantities fix mu_0?

Comment: @lalala good point, the question has been edited to make that clear

Comment: Thanks. This poses the interesting question if the fine structure constant actually has (in the sense of S. I.) a definite value.

Comment: @lalala In the [pre-2019 SI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_redefinition_of_the_SI_base_units), $\mu_0$ and $\epsilon_0$ were defined, but the definition of the ampere (whence $e$ and $\alpha$) was tied to the International Prototype Kilogram. In the new SI, electromagnetism has one experimentally-determined parameter, and it's fashionable to choose $\alpha$ rather than $\mu_0$ or $\epsilon_0$ (see e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112959/44126) for a reason why).

Comment: @lalala, that seems right from Rob and another way to look at it is, if $\mu_0$ were exactly  $4\pi...$ and $c$ is fixed, then from the speed of light formula $\epsilon_0$ would be fixed, then everything in the fine structure constant $\alpha$ would be fixed, leaving no room for measuring anything!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The organization which defines the SI is the [Bureau Internationale de Poids et Mesures (BIPM)](https://www.bipm.org/). The current version of the [SI brochure](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure) contains the definitive answer to your question (page 132):

> The previous definition of the ampere was based on the force between two current carrying conductors and had the effect of fixing the value of the vacuum magnetic permeability $μ_0$ (also known as the magnetic constant) to be exactly $\rm 4π × 10^{−7}\, H\, m^{−1} = 4π × 10^{−7}\, N\, A^{−2}$, where H and N denote the coherent derived units henry and newton, respectively. The new definition of the ampere fixes the value of $e$ instead of $μ_0$. As a result, $μ_0$ must be determined experimentally.
>
> It also follows that since the vacuum electric permittivity $ε_0$ (also known as the electric constant), the characteristic impedance of vacuum $Z_0$, and the admittance of vacuum $Y_0$ are equal to $1/μ_0c^2$, $μ_0c$, and $1/μ_0c$, respectively, the values of $ε_0$, $Z_0$, and $Y_0$ must now also be determined experimentally, and are affected by the same relative standard uncertainty as $μ_0$ since $c$ is exactly known. The product $ε_0μ_0 = 1/c^2$ and quotient $Z_0/μ_0 = c$ remain exact. At the time of adopting the present definition of the ampere, $μ_0$ was equal to $\rm 4π × 10^{−7}\, H/m$ with a relative standard uncertainty of $2.3 × 10^{−10}$.

(Minor comment: somehow copy-pasting has converted all of the $\epsilon$ and $\mu$ into an upright typeface.)

Citing the 2018 CODATA recommendations,
the NIST Constants Database [gives for $\mu_0$](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?mu0),

$$
\begin{align}
\mu_0 &= 1.256\,637\,062\,12(19)\times10^{-6} \rm \, N\, A^{-2}
\\
\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi\times10^{-7}\rm\,N\,A^{-2}}
&= 1 + (540\pm150)\times10^{-12}
\tag{NIST}
\end{align}
$$

Note that the BIPM text basically says

$$
\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi\cdots} = 1 + (0 \pm 230)\times10^{-12}
\tag{BIPM}
$$

so the BIPM and NIST/CODATA results are really only about two standard deviations apart.

The 2018 CODATA analysis, which is basically an enormous least-squares fit to the entire fundamental-constants literature, became available on 20 May 2019, which was also the effective date of the new SI. There is [a long journal article](https://www.nist.gov/programs-projects/codata-values-fundamental-physical-constants) describing the analysis leading to each set of CODATA recommended values, some of which are open-access.
It looks like [this 2017 analysis](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1681-7575/aa950a) was the basis of the BIPM's SI brochure quoted above, but the 2018 values include literature through [part](https://codata.org/initiatives/strategic-programme/fundamental-physical-constants/)
or [all](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Constants/bibliography.html) of 2018.
The [2014 paper (pdf link)](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/CODATA_JPCRD2016.pdf) contains a much more complete description of the method.

Another answer here (in its [v1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/656486/1)) quotes from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) a slightly different value
$$
\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi\cdots}-1 
\overset{?}{=}
 (820\pm200)\times10^{-12}
\tag{2018}
$$
This value is found by using [a 2018 result for the fine-structure constant](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/360/6385/191) and the definition $\mu_0 = 4\pi\alpha\hbar/e^2c$ using the new SI values.  This result was published before the CODATA-2018 cutoff, and is therefore already included, averaged with all other world data, in the NIST result quoted above. People who aren't in the fundamental-constants business should probably use the NIST result.

There is a [2020 measurement of the fine-structure constant](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-020-2964-7) which reduces the relative uncertainty on $\alpha$ (and therefore on $\mu_0$) from $150\times10^{-12}$ to $81\times10^{-12}$.  However the new result "differs by more than 5 standard deviations from the best available result [2018] from caesium recoil measurements," giving

$$
\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi\cdots}-1 
\overset{?}{=}
 (-345\pm81)\times10^{-12}
\tag{2020}
$$

In general, when there is this much tension between experimental results, a data-aggregating body like CODATA will end up with inflated uncertainties in the best-fit analysis. You can stay tuned for future measurements and CODATA-2022, but the action seems to be in measurements of $\alpha$ rather than measurements of $\mu_0$.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) we now have
$$
\mu_0= 4\pi  × 1.00000000082(20)×10^{-7} {\rm H⋅m^1}
$$

Comment: That's interesting, so within 4 standard deviations it's different to $4\pi$...

Comment: So that every book about electromagnetism before 2017 that gives $$ \mu_0 \equiv 4 \pi \times 10^{-7} \mbox{ H m}^{-1}$$ will need to be updated!

Comment: @JohnHunter Not really, because the "$4\pi$" had its own uncertainty. See my answer for a clarification about what this value actually means; the Wikipedia page misrepresented it a little.

Answer (score 1):

There is a comment at the Physics Today web site asking the same question (from P. Nelson - don't know who that is). Here's the [response](http://disq.us/p/1xiaeki) from Byron (another unknown commenter):

> c and mu_0 are defined (and thus are exact) but epsilon_0 is derived. Since it is computed from only exact quantities, epsilon_0 is also exact. Similarly, the Ampere is still exact but has a slightly different value. The Newton is derivable from the Ampere and mu_0 on the electromagnetic side and from the kg (i.e. h), the m, and the s on the mechanical side.

(Byron's comment doesn't use MathJax, so I didn't convert the symbols).

According to a [2017 article at NIST](https://www.nist.gov/publications/permeability-vacuum-and-revised-international-system-units), however, the permeability of free space is no longer a defined quantity, but a measured value, and not equal to 1 in the cgs system.

Also, [this result from NIST and CODATA 2018](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?mu0%7Csearch_for=universal_in!) which has a relative uncertainty of $1.5\times 10^{-10}$ for $\mu_0$, so it's *not* exact. Apparently, commenter Byron on the **Physics Today** site is incorrect.

$\mu_0$, indeed has become a non-exact quantity.

Comment: Thanks, although now there seem different opinions, this one says it's exact, mikes answer says it has an error

Comment: who are you gonna trust, Wikipedia or Physics Today? What does the NIST site say, or do they?

Comment: Thanks, this seems right and was upvoted.