# Is it possible to calculate the fine structure constant?

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics, physical-constants

Can this constant be derived mathematically or is derived entirely from experimental data?

Comment: The fine structure constant never comes alone; it is accompanied with factors depending on different variables of a particular problem being solved.

Answer (score 5):

It's derived experimentally, there is no known way to derive it mathematically.

As many of the constants $c$, $h$ etc. are now defined to have definite values in the new SI system  (see also [question about $\mu_0$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/656484/is-relative-permeability-mu-0-still-4-pi-times-10-7-h-m))

[image]

it really needs $\epsilon_0$ to be found experimentally, to determine the fine structure constant

as $$\alpha = \frac{e^2}{2 \epsilon_0 hc}$$

Comment: Is e in your last calculation the elementary charge or Euler's constant?

Comment: @ Derek Seabrooke , the elementary charge, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant

Comment: In [this 2012 evaluation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.5368), $\alpha$ is computed from the measurement of the electron’s anomalous magnetic moment $\frac{g-2}{2}$. The largest uncertainties on $\alpha$ come from (1) the eighth-order Feynman diagrams, (2) the tenth-order Feynman diagrams, (3) high-energy hadronic and electroweak physics, and (4) the experimental uncertainty on $(g_e-2)$.

Answer (score 4):

In the standard model, the electromagnetic coupling is not a fundamental parameter. The electromagnetic interaction is just part of the more complicated electroweak interactions, the part that remains unaffected by the Higgs field, and the electromagnetic coupling has a Pythagorean dependence on the two fundamental electroweak couplings, [see "e" in this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg_angle#/media/File:Weinberg_angle_(relation_between_coupling_constants).svg).

In practice, the electromagnetic coupling is inferred from various measurements, e.g. see section 10.2. of [PDG's "Electroweak model" report](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/web/viewer.html?file=%2F2021/reviews/rpp2020-rev-standard-model.pdf).

There have been numerous attempts to find a mathematical formula for the fine-structure constant, but such a formula would need to arise in the context of a physical theory, to truly make sense. As I mentioned, there *is* a formula for it in the electroweak theory, "e = g sin theta_W", but that simply expresses its dependence on two other quantities which are free parameters of the standard model.

Some examples of what a theory-based formula might look like:

1. If the electroweak interactions are united with the strong
   interaction in a grand unified theory, the fine-structure constant
   might be derived from a grand unified coupling equal to about 1/24
   or 1/25, which could in turn come from [a fundamental quantum
   geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3033).
2. Alternatively, the fine-structure constant can be
   expressed quite simply in terms of Feigenbaum's constant from
   dynamical systems theory ([Manasson 2008](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3300), equation 11), so maybe
   it's a kind of infrared [fixed point](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0212137).
3. Or maybe it's a parameter
   from the Deligne cohomology of the extra dimensions of string theory
   (see equation 6 forward, [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.03483)).

Comment: Manasson's formula 2πδ² seems off by a few million sigma: 136.982510520... against 137.035999084 (21) per current CODATA.

(Feigenbaum δ : https://oeis.org/A006890/constant, Sommerfeld 1/α : https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?alphinv)

Comment: @Pallas Manasson's formula could just be an approximation. The exact prediction from a full-fledged theory realizing his idea could have some additional terms. In any case, no such theory exists for now.