# According to Newton's Second Law, why is $F = \Delta p/\Delta t$ rather than just $F \propto Δp / Δt$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, time

According to 2nd law in my Textbook, Rate of Change of Momentum is **directly proportional** to magnitude of net force and is in the direction of the Net Force.

This translates to:
$F \propto Δp / Δt$

Where

- **F** = Net force
- **Δp** = Change in momentum
- **Δt** = Change in time

My book states it slightly differently, as $F = Δp / Δt$

Is this wrong, or have I made a mistake of interpreting it instead?

Comment: according to Newton's Second Law, because.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we know that $F = ma$, not $F = k \cdot ma$](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104101/)

Comment: Both are correct. Is your question why there is no proportionality constant to be seen?

Answer (score 0):

The exact law is:

$$ \mathbf{F}=\frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt} $$

so the proportionality constant is 1.