# Why is $k$ taken as 1 in the derivation of $F=kma$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, units, dimensional-analysis, si-units

In the derivation of ***F=ma***, when we reach the point ***F=kma***, we take k=1. Why can't we take 'k' as some other value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we know that $F = ma$, not $F = k \cdot ma$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104101/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We make use of S.I. units.  The statement $F=ma$ defines the newton (N) as the force required to accelerate a mass of $1kg$ by $1ms^{-2}$ in the direction of the force.  This means that $k=1$.