# Newton's second law with $F=kma$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

My book says that according to first law force applied is proportional to mass times acceleration is $$F=kma.$$
Now it says that for convenience we take $k=1$ and it does not affect anything.
But my question is if we take any other value of $k$,equations of kinetic energy, motions of equation etc would change? how can we take $k=1$ conveniently.
EDIT-Previous answers say that k=1 because force is defined so that it is "easy" to remember.
Therefore my new question is if we define F=2Ma and then derive new results for kinetic energy etc,will they be valid too?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104101/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @qmechanic please see if my new question still comes under the above link.

Comment: If you so wished, you could define the unit of force as 196133/6096 times the unit of mass times the unit of acceleration, the unit of power as  1/550 times the unit of length times the unit of force, and all kinds of other craziness. Everything will work just fine -- so long as you remember to carry all those different proportionality factors. Except it's crazy. There's only one major country in the world that indulges in this craziness.