# Why we take $k=1$ in $F=ma$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, dimensional-analysis

I know that $F$ is directly proportional to mass and acceleration but why in formula we take $k=1$ not other constant?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why the close vote? This is a perfectly good conceptual question. Sure, if you've done this stuff for years, you've internalized the concept and can perhaps no longer perceive it...

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104101/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5):

> I know that F is directly proportional to mass and acceleration but why in formula we take k=1 not other constant?

This depends on your system of units. For SI units $$\Sigma \vec F = m \vec a$$ but for US customary units $$\Sigma \vec F = k \ m \vec a$$ where $$k=\frac{1}{32.2}\mathrm{\ \frac{lb_f \ s^2}{lb_m \ ft}}$$

This is not limited to Newtons laws. Any time that you see a dimensionful universal constant in a law of physics, that constant can be removed by choosing appropriate units. For example, Gauss’ law has $\epsilon_0$ in SI units, but it goes away in Heaviside Lorentz units. Similarly Coulomb’s law has $k_e$ in SI units, but it goes away in Gaussian units.

Dimensionful universal constants describe your units, not nature. That is why the SI is now explicitly defined in terms of universal constants.

Answer (score 1):

The force was found to be proportional to the acceleration, not $ma$. This means that $F=ma$ with $m$ the constant of proportionality.