# Do accelerated particles change in size as they change in mass?

Tags: accelerator-physics

If a charged particle is accelerated to incredible energies in a particle collider, its mass increases. Does its radius increase as well and, if so, how does it compare to the change of mass? Could the mass ever become so large that the radius could no longer accommodate it?

Comment: elementary particles are point particles in the standard model of physics http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model

Answer (score 0):

Mass doesnt increase with velocity.
The concept of relativistic mass is very old which is not used by physicists now.
When velocity of particle is increased its momentum is increased not the mass.(mass remains constant).

If we classically treat the particle having some dimension then due to Lorentz contraction  the radius of the particle may decrease.
But this is not in its own frame.

read this
[Why does the (relativistic) mass of an object increase when its speed approaches that of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/why-does-the-relativistic-mass-of-an-object-increase-when-its-speed-approaches/1705#1705)

EDIT:But as @anna v said in the comment elementary particles are point particles ,they have no dimension.

Comment: Welcome.
also read the Lev Okun paper on relativistic mass.
http://www.google.co.in/search?q=lev%20okun%20relativistic%20mass