# How come waves and particles can have energy without having mass?

Tags: special-relativity, waves, photons, mass-energy

*I just want to point out that I'm still in highschool and I don't really have any advanced education within physics, however, this is something that has been on my mind. I may just be completely wrong with my knowledge regarding waves as a whole though.*

---

From my understanding of waves and objects, waves have a few defining features: being massless and having energy. Objects have mass and energy. So according to Einstein's equation $$E=mc^2$$ mass and energy go hand in hand (sort of). So, why do waves, which have energy, not have mass?

I am aware of wave-particle duality, but (now I may be wrong with this as well), to my understanding, that is regarding particles giving off weak waves and not the other way around.

Comment: What are weak waves? Can you provide more context? Mechanical waves carry energy but they do not cause a net displacement of matter.

Comment: They kind of do have mass: if I have a box with mirrored internal walls, which may or may not be full of light, I can tell that by weighing the box (if I have a very sensitive scale, or if the light inside it is extremely bright).

Comment: If any of these answers are too detailed for your present level of understanding, think of it like this — gross simplification:  waves are a way to understand the form of energy which passes from one particle with mass to another.  That energy is conceived as a coherent thing of itself, but it can also be understood as particles trading energy to their neighbors.  In other words:  it is the energy which travels across particles that themselves do not move to follow the wave.  Wave–particle duality is something else, and it only occurs on the quantum scale.

Comment: @can-ned_food This feels oversimplified to the point of being misleading. Is a wave in the ocean 'energy that passes from one particle to another'? What are the two particles in that case? What about the fact that the wave itself is made out of the collective motions of particles?

Comment: In popular physics there seems to be this huge perceived difference between 'particles' and 'waves', but it's actually quite vague.

Comment: @knzhou  Perhaps I should post something like that as an answer, so that it could be properly edited and critiqued?  Note that I didn't say that the particles carrying a wave didn't move — ocean waves, being transverse, cause the molecules of water to move, but perpendicular to the direction through which the wave is said to travel.  It looks like "anna v" already touched on some of the same things my answer would've featured, though.

Comment: @Qmechanic I think your edit of the title goes to changing the purpose of the question — and, as such, diverges from the body of the question rather much.  Of course, if you were to squeeze rest mass of particles and photons into the question, you might as well be asking a different one.  I think you guys didn't really understand the nebulous nature of the question regarding the asker's conception of ‘waves’.

Comment: @Biget  .. I hope you keep asking questions. This is a good one and that's what science is all about. I think the answer that a photon has a "rest mass" not "mass" of zero may be your answer, but I am only making this comment to say that you may enjoy the following YouTube video (if you haven't seen it already)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEKSpZPByD0

Comment: @Qmechanic : I _strongly_ object to you changing the question: it alters the question's entire meaning!

Comment: @Biget : I _think_ that the answer which emerges from this thread, overall, is that _anything_ in motion, including an electromagnetic wave, has mass because of the kinetic energy of the motion itself, even though a wave has no inherent mass: the equation E=mc^2 becomes m=E/c^2 (i.e. the tiny kinetic energy divided by the wave's speed gives a tiny mass to an otherwise massless wave).

Answer (score 46):

Equation $E=mc^2$ is incomplete. The proper form is (in units with $c=1$) $E=\sqrt{m^2+p^2}$. When an object is at rest then $E=m$ is recovered. But for massless objects $E=p$. So this means that even objects which have no mass can have energy because they have momentum, and waves carry momentum. Massless objects can never be at rest.

Comment: Actually, no, the proper form of that equation is $E^2 = m^4 + p^4$. Your form doesn't work for negative or complex energy.

Comment: You can't have the energy to be quadratic in p, instead of the square root dependence. This is the energy momentum relation for the linear theory. Maybe a typo? And I don't think we need to use negative or complex energies to address the question.

Comment: I was taught as E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4, @JanDvorak the dimensions don't add up for yours

Comment: @jk. ah, sorry. I was a bit confused by the answerer's leaving out of $c$.

Comment: Although I understand the benefits of considering $c = 1$, I think that for this question it will only be an extra source of possible confusion.

Comment: Actually, the equation $E=mc^2$ is complete, just that the mass $m$ is not the rest mass. With that in mind, the full equation is $E^2 = m_0^2c^4 + p^4c^4$, where $m_0$ is the rest mass, that is the mass of the particle at rest.

Comment: @jure Just to mention it: While it is true that $E=mc^2$ is complete when you take $m=\gamma m_0$, [we don't really do the "mass increases with speeds close to $c$" thing anymore](http://www.marco-learningsystems.com/pages/roche/what-is-mass.pdf). In most modern physics texts, all $m$s refer to the rest mass. Also, see answers in http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1686/19979

Comment: Warning to people reading the comments: all of the comments from people here are correct. All of the comments from people coming from StackOverflow are wrong.

Comment: @knzhou which are which? I am not from "here" and I find that statement confusing. But by your statement im wrong, so whatever.

Comment: @knzhou ah, no, I actually was confused by that.

Comment: @jure: You'd better delete your comment that is highly upvoted despite being **wrong**.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: To determine if someone is from here, vs. from Stack Overflow, and therefore if their comments are all correct or all wrong, the simplest approach is to ask them this question: "If I asked someone else from the same site as you whether you're from this site, what would (s)he say?"

Comment: @ruakh that makes no sense. Also, my point was that you didn't explain who was from this site so to an outsider... there is **no way to determine who is actually from physics.se**. So all your comment made conveyed to *me* is that there are inaccurate comments here and I have no way of determining which ones are correct.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: I am not knzhou. **My** comment was a joke (a reference to logic puzzles) . . . and you should calm down. (In all seriousness, though, since this seems to be bothering you: you can get a fair sense of whether a commenter is "from here" by his/her reputation score, which you can obtain by hovering over his/her username. Those of us with scores of 101, or just a little bit higher it, are probably here from sister sites. Those with scores over 500 are probably "local". Those in-between, I have no idea, and are probably half-right. :-) )

Comment: @JanDvorak There is no such a thing as complex or negative energy. Hamiltonian always need to be bounded from below. So you can always shift it by a constant to make it positive. Moreover, in this question, we are talking about single, free particles their energy is strictly positive. Complex energies can be used to describe unstable particles but then you need to work in QFT and not in a single particle theory.

Comment: @Veritas So, when we want to power our warp drive or keep a wormhole open, we need to create the necessary substances in place? I hoped I could haul them in with a freighter ship.

Comment: @JanDvorak I think you confused physics.SE with SciFun.SE

Comment: @Hamsteriffic I tend to disagree. If you write $E=mc^2$ in units with $c=1$ you immediately wonder why two different symbols denote the same quantity. In general, I agree that proper SI units should be used to answer elementary questions but the confusion that usually surrounds famous $E=mc^2$ makes it an exception. With $c=1$ you can immediately realize that something is missing.

Answer (score 14):

Well, think about photons. The electromagnetic field can cange the energy of charged matter, so it has to store energy. EM waves interact with matter and can accelerate or decelerate it, as evident from everyday life.

But let's think about it in a relativistic field theory approach. It is a change in perspective that you have to make, when you want to study a relativistic field theory. And, at speeds that approach (or reach, in the case of the photon) the speed of light, relativistic field theory is the way to go, so it's good to develop some intuition.

Let me start with a massive field, of mass $m$. Think about it just as a field, like the EM field: a law associating to each point in space a value, a vector or any kind of item. I will clarify the concept of the field "having mass" shortly. Now, in the simplest case (free field) we can say that the field has zero energy when it vanishes everywhere. Any excited configuration (nonvanishing field) has a positive energy. Consider a plane wave propagating: from the Lagrangian (I won't go into details), you have that the energy of this plane wave in relation to its impulse $p$ is
$$
E(p)=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}.
$$
Now, the group velocity of those waves (roughly speaking, the velocity at which an envelope moves) is
$$
v_g=\frac{\partial E}{\partial p}=\frac{p}{E}c.
$$
As it's obvious that $E>p$, this number is always smaller than $c$. The group velocity of this field cannot be greater than the speed of light, if you have a non zero mass. You can define the mass through the $E(p)$ relation.

This is for massive waves. Massless waves are different: for those, the dispersion relation is
$$
E(p)=|p|c.
$$
Calculating the group velocity as a derivative, you have $v_g=c$, massless waves move with group velocity $c$, the speed of light. But they still have energy, due to the fact that a wave configuration is a non zero configuration of the field. You can see this as a limit $m\to0$, even if this is not the most correct way to think about it. Massless waves always travel at the speed of light, and their dispersion relation is totally different from the massive dispersion relation.

Still, massless waves have energy, because they can interact with matter exchanging energy. So, in relativistic field theory, it's not strange at all to have massless energetic fields, as energy is a way to quantify your "energetic distance" from the vacuum configuration, when the field is 0 everywhere (and does not interact with other objects).

EDIT: to give an example about how the EM field accelerates objects in everyday life, we can go to nonrelativistic theory of interaction of light with matter. In this case one should really use QM, but we will stick with the classical model to give an intuitive example. You can describe a solid quite roughly as a set of electrons, of an effective mass $m^*$. You can mimic the interactions between electrons using a relaxation parameter $\tau$. Now, let an EM wave $\vec E$ hit the solid: the motion equations for the electron are
$$
m^*\ddot{\vec x}+\frac{m^*}\tau\dot{\vec x}=-e\vec E
$$
Now, with an oscillating wave you can try an oscillating solution, and find out that the electrons will oscillate around their initial position, with a damping. The electrons are accelerated, as they absorb enegy from the EM field.

This is the basic of the Drude model, that is described in every good book of statistical physics or solid state physics. This model explains macroscopic properties of a material by describing it microscopically and applying statistical tools. Now, the Drude model quite fails at low temperatures as it is based on classical mechanics, but its lesson is still valid: EM field interacts with an object, exciting (or accelerating, in a classical viewpoint) the charges inside the material and causing the conduction of electrical current inside the material and emission of photons outside of it, photons that will allow you to see the body when they reach your eye. You see accelerated electrons everyday when you $\textit{see anything}$: simply, you perceive them through the photons that they emit. But the emission of those photons is due to excitation (or acceleration) of the components of the material from external sources, like the massless EM waves that come from the Sun or a simple lamp.

Comment: Obviously, I accept that EM waves interact with matter, since I'd be unable to see if they didn't. But I can't think of an everyday example of EM waves accelerating an object. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I will edit the answer to give you another kind of example and way to see it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby If you accept that EM waves can exert forces on matter, then it's literally just $F = ma$. It's just that the $a$ typically oscillates very fast.

Comment: @David At the macroscopic scale the Japanese deployed a test-scale light sail on a recent Venus probe. It saved them more than a km/s in delta V. At an intermediate scale the interaction between electromagnetic waves and the free electron in an antenna is how radios work. Then at the atomic scale Salvatore's example of the Drude model was what I was reaching for as well.

Answer (score 11):

> , from my understanding of waves and object, waves have a few defining features: being massless and having energy.

[Waves](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Sound/wavplt.html) have been observed in water, to start with, and then it was found that sound can be described with waves, i.e. as solutions of differential [wave equations](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/waveq.html), as also strings can display wave behavior.

A water wave can be described by the energy it carries and the height/amplitude of the wave. But it is riding on a medium (which has mass), a huge number of molecules of water whose mass is not relevant to the classical water wave description (it is implicit in the constants that describe the behavior of the fluid).

[image: Waves]

> Waves may be graphed as a function of time or distance. A single frequency wave will appear as a sine wave in either case. From the distance graph the wavelength may be determined. From the time graph, the period and frequency can be obtained. From both together, the wave speed can be determined.

Light waves are classical, and they transfer energy, but it has been [experimentally found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment) that they are not riding on a medium.

This brings us to the quantum mechanical frame where $E = mc^2$ is relevant and defined.

Actually, for particles at the quantum mechanical framework the energy is $E^2 = p^2 + m_0^2$, where [special relativity](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/relcon.html) has to be used and there are four vectors, $(E, p_x,p_y,p_z)$ and the $m_0$ is the "length" of this four-vector. (Here we assume the c, the velocity of light, is 1).

> Object have mass and energy.

Classical objects.

> So according to Einstein's equation $E=mc^2$, mass and energy go hand in hand (sort of)

See above and links given for the quantum mechanical objects.

> so why do waves, which have energy not have mass?

Classical waves ride on atoms and molecules, which have mass.

Electromagnetic waves classically have varying electric and magnetic fields in space and time, and quantum mechanically they are riding on photons which have mass 0 by the special relativity equations; they just have energy equal to momentum.

> I am aware of wave-particle duality but (now I may be wrong with this as well) to my understanding that is regarding particles giving off weak waves and not the other way around.

You are confusing the two frameworks, the classical and the quantum mechanical. The wave particle duality is a quantum mechanical phenomenon, but the particles are not spread out like a classical water wave. The quantum mechanical probability density of finding by measurement a particle at a particular (x,y,z) obeys wave equations and can show interference patterns like classical waves. [This experiment of sending single electrons at a double slit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) may help to understand the difference between probability density wave behavior and particle itself.

Comment: Well, a lot of people tend to forget that scientific method never demonstrates anything, except insofar as it demonstrates the absence of something else.  Those [experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment) demonstrated that the expected medium was absent, not that there was no other medium which had different characteristics that were not detected or detectable.  Otherwise, the ultimate paragraph is concise and excellent.

Answer (score 3):

(I am repeating what others have said, but hopefully in a simpler and more accessible language)

The problem is that both energy and mass can mean more than one thing.
Energy can mean *rest energy* or *total energy*. (or a number of other things)
Mass can mean *rest mass* or *relativistic mass*.
$$E_{rest}=m_{rest}c^2$$
$$E_{total}=m_{rel}c^2$$

For a normal particle, like a uranium atom, the first equation says that it has energy even when it is sitting still.  For light, which has zero rest mass, it says that *light sitting still* has zero energy.  Or, in other words, light cannot sit still.

The second equation says that all forms of energy has relativistic mass, including kinetic energy. For normal particles this means that they get heavier as they get faster. For light, it means that it has both non-zero energy and non-zero relativistic mass.

Now, both these equations are simple multiplications with a constant.  This suggests that energy and mass is the same thing, only measured in different units.  When other answers have said to set $c=1$, they are basically saying that things get easier if you measure $E$ and $m$ in the same units.

Physicists have taken this to heart and no longer talk about both rest mass and rest energy as that is redundant.  The term used is "rest mass" or just "mass".

Likewise, they rarely talk about "relativistic mass" but prefer to say "total energy" or just "energy".

When using this convention, you can no longer say $E=mc^2$ since *total* energy and *rest* mass does not fit together in this way.

Answer (score 1):

When you start to think about what mass is at a deeper level it becomes easier to separate it from the idea of energy. The two aren't necessarily mutually exclusive. One might think of mass as something that has a resistance to changes in velocity. One might also think of energy as what's required to change the velocity of an entity, that entity doesn't necessarily have to have an intrinsic resistance to changes in velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that waves are massless is incorrect.

A photon has zero rest mass, not zero mass.  In effect, this means that a photon can only exist when moving at the speed of light (which varies depending on the material the photon is passing through).

Comment: According to Einstein's equation (E=mc^2) , if a photon has zero mass it must also have zero energy (as its energy would be its mass, i.e. zero, multiplied by its speed, and zero multiplied by anything equals zero), so the implication in the question that a wave is massless _must_ - in some sense - be incorrect, given that the question implies that the wave has energy. If its speed is zero, i.e. it is _at rest_, then the equation is satisfied: zero energy equals zero mass multiplied by zero speed. This would be a purely theoretical state: a state of nil energy. That, I think, is what is meant.

Answer (score -2):

In a real sense, an electromagnetic wave *is* energy. Where a particle emits energy, it principally does so by emiting it in the form of electromagnetic waves. The more energy it emits, per second, the greater the frequency of the wave (the more peaks in the waveform per second) and the shorter its wavelength (the distance between those peaks).

As *only* particles couple/bind to the fabric of spacetime (as Einstein terms it), only particles have mass. Energy does *not* couple to spacetime. It is the coupling-bond which gives a particle mass (and thus inertia). As energy does not have a coupling bond, it has no inertia, which is what permits it to move at the speed of light.

In technical terms, a particle interacts with the Higgs field, thereby acquiring inertia. A wave does not interact with that field, so has no inertia. It is the Higgs field which gives an object inertia and mass. In a sense, *mass* is only a measurement of the *strength* of the coupling charge by which the particle adheres to the spacetime fabric (to what, in modern terms, I suppose we should simply call the Higgs field).

If an object (i.e. a particle) couples to spacetime, a certain amount of energy must be applied to break the coupling bond, and we term that quantum of energy "mass", a particle's mass being equivalent to the amount of energy required to break the bond which is holding it in place. But all we are really saying (from Newton) is that a particle will only move if acted upon by an outside force. Energy does not obey Newton's laws of motion, in the sense that electromagnetic energy (waves) move although no outside force is acting on them.

Hence an object which has mass, and thus obeys Newton's laws of motion, we define as a particle. And an object which does not, we define as energy. Energy has no mass by definition, since mass implies inertia, but a waveform has no inertia (when did you last stand in the sunlight and experience being knocked to the ground by it?)

It is, perhaps, wrong to say that waves *have* energy. It is probably less inacurate to say that waves *are* energy. Mass has energy, too: Einstein explained that energy equals mass multiplied by the square of the speed of light. Mass is energy is a confined state. But *free* energy is free in the sense of being unconstrained, and that degree of freedom comes from *not* having mass, which is really only another term for inertia.

Comment: Paragraph 1 is wrong. It's very dangerous to say something "is" energy. In standard physics language, energy is a property of objects, not an object itself. What you're doing is like saying an expensive painting _is_ money.

Comment: Paragraph 2 is exactly backwards. Energy affects the curvature of spacetime; in fact, it's basically the _only_ thing that does.

Comment: Paragraph 3 is wrong. The 'spacetime fabric' and 'Higgs field' are completely unrelated things. The Higgs mechanism doesn't involve general relativity at all. Also, there's no clear distinction between "particles" and "waves" at the quantum level.

Comment: Paragraph 4 is wrong. Mass is not quantized, period.

Comment: @knzhou Why not write an answer?

Comment: @knzhou  ‘Money’ isn't a good analogue in this case, because it is a class of objects rather than a property thereof.  ‘Currency’ could be nearer, but then what is the difference between an extrinsic property and an intrinsic one but the boundaries of definition?  What is ‘redness’ but a way to describe a systemic interpretation of the way a certain ‘object’ interacts with other such objects?

Comment: @ knzhou. The question implies (incorrectly) that energy is a property of waves, i.e. that the term "waves" is _not_ merely a synonym for energy. I didn't say that energy is an object, only that electromagnetic waves are one type of energy (gravity waves are another). I didn't even mention the curvature of spacetime: if I had, I would have pointed out that it is _mass_ which causes spacetime to curve (even though mass is actually a confined state of energy).

Comment: /Continued/  The Higgs field, which gives mass (and inertia) to particles only, is the key to _understanding_ the distinction between particles and energy, i.e. why energy does not have mass. Even though the Higgs field is one phenomenon, and electromagnetism is a separate phenomenon, the absence of inertia is nonetheless the key to _understanding_ why an electromagnetic wave doesn't have mass.